# How to align the text to the center in DTAttributedTextView

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, text-alignment

I am using the DTAttributedTextView to show the html data in the nsstring format.Is there a way to align the text in this view to the center.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done like this & add your code to it-

```
  NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
        [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
        [html appendString:@"body {"];
     [html appendString:@"<center>"];
        [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
        [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
        [html appendString:@"}"];
     [html appendString:@"<center>"];
        [html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head>"];
      [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];
```